# Unable to get value of password parameter into another parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In Jenkins pipeline parameter say `Branches` of type `Active Choice Reactive Parameter`, I've to auto-populate branch names hence I've following command, which I can execute in parameter's Groovy script -

```
svn ls <url> --non-interactive --no-auth-cache --trust-server-cert --username <username>--password <password>
```

`username` can be retrieved using `User.current().getId()`

I've `Password` parameter of `Password Parameter` type. To use value of this parameter in Groovy script of `Branches`, I've added `Password` parameter in `Referenced parameters` of `Branches`

But I cannot see its value reflected in `Branches` parameter. Can you please suggest how this can be handled?

Or any other way to pass Password value or authentication details so I can execute svn command.

Comment: Code and everything was correct. Only thing is I was not having correct password in Password parameter, hence expected result was not returned.

Answer (score -1):

Could [credentials binding plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/) be the answer?

The idea is to add svn user and password to Jenkins credentials store and then use it in the pipeline.

```
withCredentials([
    usernamePassword(
        credentialsId: 'mySvnLogin',
        usernameVariable: 'USER',
        passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')]) {
    sh '''
      svn ls <url> --non-interactive --no-auth-cache --trust-server-cert --username $USER 
 --password $PASSWORD
    ''''
```

Comment: Active Choice parameters use Groovy scripts which are not part of Pipeline code.  `withCredentials` is a Pipeline step and is therefore unavailable in the Groovy scripts for Active Choice parameters.

Comment: Code and everything was correct. Only thing is I was not having correct password in Password parameter, hence expected result was not returned.